# Why is the directory throwing 404 when rendering ejs

Tags: node.js, http, express, ejs

I am trying to make a page which just receives a get request from my index.js file and just displays "hello user". I have created a 'users.ejs' file in my express app which just renders a string from a 'users.js' file. There is a form in my index.ejs file which redirects to my users directory. The index file works well when I type the '/' directory in the url box but for some reason, the file throws a 404 not found error in the browser when I hit the submit on the form in the first page instead of showing the 'users.ejs' page, can anyone tell me why it does this?

index.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p><br>

    <form action='/users' method='get'> 
      Enter Name: <input type='text' name='thetext'></input><br><br>
      <input type='submit' id='checkresponse'>enter</button>
    </form>
   
    <script type = 'text/javascript' src = '/dist/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type = 'text/javascript' src = '/js/response.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Expr-Ass' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

users.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('users', {star:'Sparksiano'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

users.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= star %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome user!</h1>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of comments below you may want to try something like this:

users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* Notice the path change */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('users', {star:'Sparksiano'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

It sounds like you may be mounting your path to include a /users and then having a route that has a path of /users.  Would be easier to troubleshoot if you posted the rest of the server side code.

Comment: Yes, I set the view engine to ejs in  app.js

Comment: Can you confirm you are being sent to the correct url?  You don't show the code where you are mounting your express router. But are you being sent to localhost:port/users and mounting the router correctly.

Comment: I have the following lines directing to my router files
_italic_ **bold** `app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);`

Comment: So the correct url would be localhost:port/users/users if you are mounting with a base path of /users and then adding a route with a path of /users.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me figure out my problem

Answer (score 0):

I place the various ejs files in a folder and then point the express router to use that folder as a path:

```
var app = express();

app.set('port', 6000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Then I route them to those pages:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {title: 'Express'});
});

app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  res.render('users', {star:'Sparksiano'});
});
```

Make sure the users.ejs page is in the same folder.